# Criar um .bat <origem>"nomearquivo_2021_01_10_codigo" <destino>\\outro servidor

Tags: prompt, bat

Criei um [.bat](/questions/tagged/.bat) que estava funcional e houve a necessidade de modificar para selecionar e copiar arquivos pelo mês de cada ano vigente para um storage.

Nome do arquivo:   `AMARGOSA_GCTRANS_backup_2021_01_10_003001_3995647.bak`

```
@echo off

cd \

echo -------------------------------------

echo      Iniciando o backup

echo -------------------------------------

echo

echo -------------------------------------

echo   Pasta Backup_SQL_Mensal

echo -------------------------------------

xcopy /y /d F:\Backup\gyc\Amargosa\Backup Banco de Dados\AMARGOSA_teste\AMARGOSA_teste_backup_2021_01_10_003001_3995647.bak \\192.168.0.120\Backup_SQL_Mensal\Amargosa\Backup Banco de Dados\AMARGOSA_teste

echo .....

echo -------------------------------------

echo      Backup concluído

echo -------------------------------------

echo

pause
```

Comment: Olá Adriano, eu não entendi o seu problema, poderia explicar melhor?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Para cada execução, pegue a data:

```batch-file
> wmic OS Get localdatetime

20210128183243.207000-180
```

**2.** Salve em uma variável usando um **`for /f`** loop

```batch-file
> for /f %i in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^|findstr /r [0-9]')do set "_data=%i"

set "_data=20210128183243.207000-180"
```

**3.** Use sub-strings para compor o layout de data/strings dos nomes dos seus arquivos:

```batch-file
> set "_data=20210128183243.207000-180"
obter string da posição 0 até a posição 4   ==> 2021 0128183243.207000-180
                              %_data:~4,2%  ==> 2021 obter o ano corrente 


> set "_data=20210128183243.207000-180"
obter string partindo da posição 4 use as 2 posições seguintes   ==> 2021 01 28183243.207000-180
                                                   %_data:~4,2%  ==>      01 obter o mês vigente
```

**4.** Concatene o caractere **"`_`"** com as sub-strings da variável **`%date%`** para **ano** e
também para o **mês** vigente, assim compondo uma seleção para os nomes de seus arquivos **`.bak`** de origem.

```batch-file
AMARGOSA_teste_backup_2021_01_10_003001_3995647.bak
                  *_%_data:~0,4%_%_data:~4,2%_*.bak
```

**5.** Selecionar *"...pela data / mês de cada ano vigente..."*, sabendo que não vai existir (supostamente) arquivos com mês **10** em mês vigente **06**, basta apenas usar o ano vigente, assim o seu mês (em sub-strings) pode ser substituído por **`_*_`**:

```batch-file
.\*_%_data:~0,4%_*_*.bak
```

**6.** Junte tudo no seu bat:

```batch-file
@echo off

echo -------------------------------------

echo Iniciando o backup

echo -------------------------------------

echo

echo -------------------------------------

echo . Pasta Backup_SQL_Mensal

echo -------------------------------------

cd /d "F:\Backup\gyc\Amargosa\Backup Banco de Dados\AMARGOSA_teste\"

xcopy /y /d ".\*_%_data:~0,4%_%_data:~4,2%_*.bak" "\\192.168.0.120\Backup_SQL_Mensal\Amargosa\Backup Banco de Dados\AMARGOSA_teste\"

echo .....

echo -------------------------------------

echo Backup concluído

echo -------------------------------------

echo

pause
```

- Algumas leituras adicionais in **//English**

  [√] **[`Cd /d`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**

  [√] **[`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[`Xcopy /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[Substring in Set command (Refer: `!_var:~x,y!`)](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**

  [√]: **[Parsing dates in batch files regional settings locale](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/02/parsing-dates-in-batch-files-regional-settings-locale/)**

  [√]: **[Safe way to get current day month and year in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635541/safe-way-to-get-current-day-month-and-year-in-batch)**

  [√]: **[How do i get current date time on the windows command line in a suitable-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format/19799236#19799236)**